# Is Kalara formerly Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

[image]

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kalara) says this:

> Kalara, formerly Jessica Wolff, was a Human female who served as an Federation Starfleet officer until she was stranded on the planet Altamid. Wolff became the alien Kalara after the use of energy transference technology severely mutated her body.

Where is this confirmed in the movie?

Comment: I don't think this can be confirmed until the film is released on streaming or home video, but some online sources are claiming that the photos of Franklin crew members Jessica Wolff and Anderson Le are identifiable as Kalara and Manas. I supposed they may be recognizable as the actors' real human faces? If so, that's a neat easter egg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes.

Prior to her transformation, courtesy of the alien device used to prolong her life, **Kalara was a Starfleet officer called Jessica Wolff.** We see her personnel records at the end of the film along with those of Krall (Captain Balthazar Edison) and Manas (Anderson Le).

The actress depicted as Jessica Wolff is the same actress that plays Kalara, [Lydia Wilson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3575723/). She also appears earlier in the film as one of the officers seen in the video sequence where Krall is identified by Uhura.

[image]
<sub><sup>(image slightly processed to enhance script)</sup></sub>

Comment: You're always welcome to the screening! By the way, you might want to slow down with edits a bit ;)

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Please pass along my apologies in the chatroom for dominating the front page. I'm trying to pace these edits in between everyone else's questions and answers but you're all just so damn sloooooow.